# Optimize Code to Extract String as an Array between a specific keyword

Tags: string, optimization, groovy

I am trying to extract invoice which is surrounded between a boundary keyword in groovy, in the below example boudary key word is `a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b` and I tried extracting the invoice between the boundary and elimated the `Content-Type` line

```
String BOUNDARY = "boundary"
def file = '''MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 17 May 2017 20:59:57 +2
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg="SHA256"; boundary="a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b"


--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

LEDES98BI V2[]
INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID|INVOICE_TOTAL|BILLING_START_DATE|BILLING_END_DATE|INVOICE_DESCRIPTION|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER|EXP/FEE/INV_ADJ_TYPE|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS|LINE_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT|LINE_ITEM_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_DATE|LINE_ITEM_TASK_CODE|LINE_ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE|LINE_ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE|TIMEKEEPER_ID|LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION|LAW_FIRM_ID|LINE_ITEM_UNIT_COST|TIMEKEEPER_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION|CLIENT_MATTER_ID|PO_NUMBER|CLIENT_TAX_ID|MATTER_NAME|INVOICE_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_NET_TOTAL|INVOICE_CURRENCY|TIMEKEEPER_LAST_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_FIRST_NAME|ACCOUNT_TYPE|LAW_FIRM_NAME|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_1|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_2|LAW_FIRM_CITY|LAW_FIRM_STATEorREGION|LAW_FIRM_POSTCODE|LAW_FIRM_COUNTRY|CLIENT_NAME|CLIENT_ADDRESS_1|CLIENT_ADDRESS_2|CLIENT_CITY|CLIENT_STATEorREGION|CLIENT_POSTCODE|CLIENT_COUNTRY|LINE_ITEM_TAX_RATE|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TYPE|INVOICE_REPORTED_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_TAX_CURRENCY[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|1|F|2.00|-70|630|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research Attorney's fees, Set off claim|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|22240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|100.80|VAT|100.80|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|2|F|2.00|0|700|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research attorney's fees, Trial pleading|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|112.00|VAT|112.00|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|3|F|0.200|0|40|19990116|L510||A107|45875|Telephone conference with John Doe|24-6437381|200|Beaster, John|ASSOC|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Beaster|John|O|||||||||||||||.16|6.40|VAT|6.40|[]
--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b'''
def boundaryline = file.split( '\n' ).find{it.contains( 'boundary' ) }
def boundary = boundaryline.substring(boundaryline.indexOf(BOUNDARY) + BOUNDARY.length()+1).replaceAll('"','')

def invoice = file.split("--"+boundary)[1] // find inovoice between boundary string
def lines = invoice.trim().split('\\[]')
def headerLine = lines[0].trim().split('\n') //eleminating content type from header line
def header = headerLine[headerLine.length-1]
lines[0] = header //assigning header to first index
println lines
```

I am getting the expected output as below

```
    [LEDES98BI V2, 
INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID|INVOICE_TOTAL|BILLING_START_DATE|BILLING_END_DATE|INVOICE_DESCRIPTION|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER|EXP/FEE/INV_ADJ_TYPE|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS|LINE_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT|LINE_ITEM_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_DATE|LINE_ITEM_TASK_CODE|LINE_ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE|LINE_ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE|TIMEKEEPER_ID|LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION|LAW_FIRM_ID|LINE_ITEM_UNIT_COST|TIMEKEEPER_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION|CLIENT_MATTER_ID|PO_NUMBER|CLIENT_TAX_ID|MATTER_NAME|INVOICE_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_NET_TOTAL|INVOICE_CURRENCY|TIMEKEEPER_LAST_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_FIRST_NAME|ACCOUNT_TYPE|LAW_FIRM_NAME|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_1|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_2|LAW_FIRM_CITY|LAW_FIRM_STATEorREGION|LAW_FIRM_POSTCODE|LAW_FIRM_COUNTRY|CLIENT_NAME|CLIENT_ADDRESS_1|CLIENT_ADDRESS_2|CLIENT_CITY|CLIENT_STATEorREGION|CLIENT_POSTCODE|CLIENT_COUNTRY|LINE_ITEM_TAX_RATE|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TYPE|INVOICE_REPORTED_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_TAX_CURRENCY, 
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|1|F|2.00|-70|630|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research Attorney's fees, Set off claim|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|22240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|100.80|VAT|100.80|, 
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|2|F|2.00|0|700|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research attorney's fees, Trial pleading|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|112.00|VAT|112.00|, 
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|3|F|0.200|0|40|19990116|L510||A107|45875|Telephone conference with John Doe|24-6437381|200|Beaster, John|ASSOC|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Beaster|John|O|||||||||||||||.16|6.40|VAT|6.40|]
```

My code has so many String manipulations, can it be optimized and refactored to a better version?

Comment: you are doing two things which are protocol & data parsing together. you need to make two concerns separated. and there are many MIME protocol parsers and cvs parsers you can found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ your message seems to be mutipart except the final boundary 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

2/ in case if you are looking for groovy sample with using existing libs:

```
//instead of grab you can download mail.jar directly and place into classpath
//https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7
@Grab(group='javax.mail', module='mail', version='1.4.7')

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource

def file = '''MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 17 May 2017 20:59:57 +2
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg="SHA256"; boundary="a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b"


--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

LEDES98BI V2[]
INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID|INVOICE_TOTAL|BILLING_START_DATE|BILLING_END_DATE|INVOICE_DESCRIPTION|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER|EXP/FEE/INV_ADJ_TYPE|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS|LINE_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT|LINE_ITEM_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_DATE|LINE_ITEM_TASK_CODE|LINE_ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE|LINE_ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE|TIMEKEEPER_ID|LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION|LAW_FIRM_ID|LINE_ITEM_UNIT_COST|TIMEKEEPER_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION|CLIENT_MATTER_ID|PO_NUMBER|CLIENT_TAX_ID|MATTER_NAME|INVOICE_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_NET_TOTAL|INVOICE_CURRENCY|TIMEKEEPER_LAST_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_FIRST_NAME|ACCOUNT_TYPE|LAW_FIRM_NAME|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_1|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_2|LAW_FIRM_CITY|LAW_FIRM_STATEorREGION|LAW_FIRM_POSTCODE|LAW_FIRM_COUNTRY|CLIENT_NAME|CLIENT_ADDRESS_1|CLIENT_ADDRESS_2|CLIENT_CITY|CLIENT_STATEorREGION|CLIENT_POSTCODE|CLIENT_COUNTRY|LINE_ITEM_TAX_RATE|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TYPE|INVOICE_REPORTED_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_TAX_CURRENCY[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|1|F|2.00|-70|630|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research Attorney's fees, Set off claim|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|22240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|100.80|VAT|100.80|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|2|F|2.00|0|700|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research attorney's fees, Trial pleading|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|112.00|VAT|112.00|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|3|F|0.200|0|40|19990116|L510||A107|45875|Telephone conference with John Doe|24-6437381|200|Beaster, John|ASSOC|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Beaster|John|O|||||||||||||||.16|6.40|VAT|6.40|[]
--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b
'''
//i've added a new line at the end to be compatible with multipart message 

//convert to datasource
def fileDS = new FileDataSource("message.bin"){
    @Override public InputStream getInputStream(){
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    }
}
//build MimeMultipart
def msg = new MimeMultipart(fileDS)
//get first part
println msg.getBodyPart(0).getInputStream().getText("UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!! is the index for getBodyPart method always 0? if so why?

Comment: also `msg.getBodyPart(0).getInputStream().getText("UTF-8")` works in groovy, but in Java its throwing compiler error, how do I make this work in Java?

Comment: getBodyPart : you should see MimeMultipart class doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html  Your message could contain several parts divided by boundary. getBodyPart(0) returns the first part, but you can go through all parts and choose the right part by file name or by header (in your case Content-Type present).

Comment: InputStream.getText() - is a groovy feature: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html  / in java 8 you can use `new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) ).lines()...` / 
Or you can use apache commons-io library to convert content of the input stream to string : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)